# Unable to display simple has_one association: undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I apologize if this may seem like a duplicate but I have not seen a solution explained clearly.  I have a simple has_one, belongs_to association

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :book_attributes
  has_one :book
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book, :allow_destroy => true  
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :author_id
  belongs_to :author
end
```

The authors_controller

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authors = Author.includes(:book).all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @authors }
    end
  end

 def show
    @author = Author.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @author }
    end
  end

 def new
    @author = Author.new
    @book = @author.build_book    

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @author }
    end
  end
```

This Show.html.erb is the show stopper, the @author.book.title is giving me a undefined method for nil:NilClass:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @author.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Book:</b>
  <%= @author.book.title %><br/>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_author_path(@author) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', authors_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the Author you're trying to show has a nil Book. So when you do `@author.book.title`, you'll get the error since `title` is not a method on nil:NilClass.

To fix this, you'll either need to check for a nil title by:

```
@author.book.try(:title)
```

Or just make sure all authors always have a book before they're considered valid by adding this to your Author model:

```
validates :book_id, :presence => true
```

Comment: I'm unable to get validates working with the :book_attributes or something similar

Answer (score 0):

If the author doesn't have a book, `@author.book` will return `nil`, so you then go on to call `nil.title` and it blows up.

You need to guard against this case. Perhaps an `if` statement around the code in question:

```
<% if @author.book %>
  <%= @author.book.title %>
<% else %>
  (none)
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Book is nil because it hasn't been assigned to the Author yet.

```
<%= @author.book.nil? ? link_to 'Add Book', path(@author) : @author.book.title %>
```

or

```
<%= @author.book.nil? ? 'No Titles available' : @author.book.title %>
```